# How can I pass along an array of floats as a uniform to shaders from Three JS

Tags: three.js, webgl

To clarify I am using Three JS, React-Three-Fiber, React

I have disc with points mapped on it, I have calculated the distance of every point to the center of the desk and stored results in an array. I would like to pass this array to the shaders but I am struggling to understand how to do it. I read in the docs you can also pass along `vec3,mat3,float` essentially. My array has a length of 1000 so I cannot use it with any of the data types uniforms can be used with, if I store the array as a `define` how can I go about using it in the shader file?

uniforms

```
  const uniforms = useMemo(() => ({
    uTime: {
      value: 0.0
    },
    uRadius: {
      value: radius
    },
    uDistance: {
      value: normalDistances
    }
  }), [])
```

fragment shader

```
const fragmentShader = `
uniform vec3 uDistance;

varying float vDistance;

  void main() {

    float x = uDistance[52];

    vec3 color = vec3(0.5, 0.5, x);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
  }

`

export default fragmentShader
```

I cannot import a uniform without specifying the data type, and I cannot find how to import a define which was passed along from javascript. Does anyone know what my issue is? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uniform vec3 uDistance;
```

This is no valid declaration of a uniform array. You always have to define the length like so:

```
uniform vec3 uDistance[8];
```

However, keep in mind that uniform arrays require a uniform vector for each entry. If you want to use a length of 1000, you easily hit the maximum supported uniform vectors on devices.

I suggest you encode your distance data into a texture and then sample it in your shader. In `three.js`, you can use the [DataTexture](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/DataTexture) class for this.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, to clarify for myself the way you declare an array in the GLSL file is by `uniform vec3 uDistance[8];`  where uDistance has a length of 8? How do I access array elements?

Comment: On the javascript side would uDistance look something like `.. value: [vec3(0.01), vec3(0.5), vec3(0.9)]`

Comment: You access e.g. the first entry of the array like so: `uDistance[0]`.

Comment: `vec3(0.01)` is no valid JavaScript or `three.js` syntax. You want to use `THREE.Vector3`.